# How to use exception-involved head only library in exception-disabled C++ project?

Tags: c++, templates, exception, g++

My C++17 project is compiled by g++ with flag `-fno-exceptions`, and it works fine.
But there appears a problem when I replaced the logging library with a new one.
The new logging library is head-only and full of templates, and uses `try/catch/throw`s.
Compilation fails.

I can't wrap this head-only library into an isolated shared lib,
because I don't think it's possible to specialize all templates I need, especially codes like this:

```
template <typename ... Args>
void log(const char * f, const Args & ... args); // log("%d,%d", 0, 1);
```

Any solution? I really wanna this new library. Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the of the logging library? Is it public? Can you show more code of it which do `try/catch/throw`? How many times `try/catch/throw` is used?

Comment: @MarekR Actually it is an old version of [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog). For some stupid reason, I have to use version [0.10.0](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/tree/v0.10.0). spdlog solved this problem in later version.

Comment: Well you can have either `-fno-exceptions` or `try/catch/throw`, not both.